# Puppeteer: How to open tabs in an already active browser window?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, chromium

I've been writing a simple program that opens several pages and performs some simple scraping, and login functions. I have already managed to open new pages on new tabs once I run the browser, but when the browser is already open I am unable to open more tabs in that same browser, and have to open them in a new different browser window.

Is there any workaround this? Or is there any way to get puppeteer to open new pages in the same browser window if a browser window is already open? Thanks in advance.

## My code is structured like this:

**index.js (main application file)**

```
async function runBrowser(pageID) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        "headless": false,
        "defaultViewport": null,
        "args": ['--start-maximized'],
    });
//CHANGE THE PAGE THAT OPENS
    switch(pageID){
        case 0:
        login.openCursosPuntoD(browser);
        break;
        case 1:
        facebook.openFacebookPuntoD(browser);
        break;
        case 2:
        instagram.openInstagramPuntoD(browser);
        break;
        case 3:
        twitter.openTwitterPuntoD(browser);
        break;
        case 4:
        youTube.openYouTubePuntoD(browser);
        break;
        case 5:
        webPage.openPaginaWebPuntoD(browser);
        break;
        default:
        break;
    }
};
runBrowser(0);
```

**instagramPuntoD.js (an example of an open function file)**

```
function openInstagramPuntoD(browser){
actions.runPage('https://www.instagram.com/xxxx/',false,browser);
};
module.exports = {
  openInstagramPuntoD,
};
```

**actions.js (contains functions of actions that the scraper can perform)**

```
async function runPage(url,doLogin,browser){
    const page = [];
    const pageNumber = (await browser.pages()).length+1;
    page[pageNumber] = await browser.newPage();
    await page[pageNumber].goto(url);
      
if(doLogin == true){
    var user = getUsername();
    var pass = getPassword();
    login(user,pass,page[pageNumber]);
}
else{}
}
```

***NOTE** The irrelevant parts of the code were excluded.

Answer (score 3):

Ok so after a few research,

You have to use a userDataDir to reuse the cache, and make browser reuse the current active window. Otherwise it's just start from a traditional 'open a new window'

```
puppeteer.launch({
  userDataDir: 'PATH TO DATA FOLDER',
})
```

You can find the Data Folder with `chrome://version` (Profile Path), but don't forget to erase the `/Default` as the end of the path

Comment: Thanks for the response @toykato , in this case I am passing on the browser to the runPage function in actions.js, from here I am already doing the `const page = browser.newPage();` as `page[pageNumber] = await browser.newPage(); `

Comment: Thanks again for the help @toykato, I modified the code in order to include that, and get the directory, but this creates a chrome error. "Cannot start Chrome because something went wrong with your profile."

Comment: additionally, in order to get the path, I initiate a browser instance and scrape the path. This approach only works if the browser window's headless property  is set to false. Is there any other approach you can think of? Since this solution also conflicts with other parts of my project due to the fact that i'm also using electron (which runs chromium in the background).

Comment: Did you write the runBrowser function like this ?

`async function runBrowser(pageID) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        "userDataDir": 'PATH TO DATA FOLDER',
        "headless": false,
        "defaultViewport": null,
        "args": ['--start-maximized'],
    });`

Comment: thanks for the help I was able to find a solution, your guidance helped me a lot.